# Why does $\subseteq$ symbolize subring relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation

Each of the relations: subgroup ($\leq$), proper subgroup ($\lt$), normal subgroup ($\triangleleft$) all **require** $\subseteq$ (**subset**).

However, $\subseteq$ (**subset**) is obviously not sufficient.

In the same respect (perhaps more respect), it appears reasonable that **subring** relation should not be $\subseteq$. But, it *is* $\subseteq$.

Why?

Comment: This seems particular to your book. It appears to be because your book doesn't use subsets very often.

Comment: The book says it is traditional notation for rings. Peculiar for rings is how I see it currently because "plainly" subsets appear in propositions here and there. I let it go now. :)

Comment: I have even seen the symbol $\subseteq$ in arrow diagrams to denote an inclusion morphism.

Comment: There are only so many symbols, therefore it is inevitable that some are reused to mean different things, and different books may reuse different symbols. Note that also the use of $\le$ to denote subgroups is such a reuse, as $\le$ originally is defined for numbers. Note that one might also argue that in the category of groups, a subgroup is the equivalent to a subset in the category of sets.

Comment: There is no “standard” notation for “being a subring of”. Since it's not so often used, nobody has thought of a particular notation. What's usually found is “let $S\subseteq R$ be a subring”.

Comment: @celtschk please move your comment to an answer lest I move this question to philosophy :).

Comment: Moral of the story: just always use $\rightarrowtail$.

Comment: Expecting that each individual notion has a distinct and unique notation is a wild fantasy.

Comment: @Dror: Done (with slight modification). Well, not actually moved (I wouldn't know how to do that) but copied.

Comment: @celtschk I originally wanted to ask you to 'translate' the comment to an answer. But, I didn't because it also carries precisely the opposite of what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only so many symbols, therefore it is inevitable that some are reused to mean different things, and different books may reuse different symbols. Note that also the use of $\le$ to denote subgroups is such a reuse, as $\le$ originally is defined for numbers. Note that one might also argue that in the category of rings, a subring is the equivalent to a subset in the category of sets.

Comment: Have you recommendations on good material for learning category theory?

Comment: @Dror: I don't, sorry. I never systematically learned it myself; my limited knowledge about it comes from a combination of articles about categorical quantum mechanics, some programming book whose title I don't remember (it was downloadable freely as PDF and used Scheme as programming language), Wikipedia articles and math.SE questions.

Comment: $+\omega$, apology accepted

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a boring answer, but the rationale I see is that when you are dealing with this kind of algebraic structures the underlying set construction becomes rather uninteresting, so it is generally assumed that you are not talking about the set relation.